# script tag doesn't work in head tag

Tags: javascript

script tag doesnt execute if i put it in head tag but works fine if i put it in body tag ..can anybody tell me the reason behind this?? here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because HTML is parsed from top to bottom. That means that when you try to get the element ***demo*** it is not yet created.

To make it work in the ***head*** tag you should add a listener that will fire when the page is fully loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Here the DOM elements are loaded, and you can get them with .getElementById.
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help romain!! i appreciate your kindness

Answer (score 0):

The `<head>` is for including other files and libraries and such (you can also include them in the body). But if you want to actually write JS code to manipulate the body, you have to place it in the body.

Comment: That's not necessarily correct. It's quite reasonable to write JS in the head, but you need to be aware of the lifecycle of the page. Any JS written in the head will be parsed before the body begins to load, so any JS statements referencing body elements will fail / throw an error (unless they're in functions that just defined but not called from the head section. Things like cookie management, getting external resources, querying client environment, etc, are all valid JS to be included in the head. :)